# How to order entities from one to many relationship contained in object

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

How to sort foreign key records

How can I sort foreign key records contained in an entity?

I have a one to many relationship: one Group can contain many Sites.

Group.java

```
public class Group implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3698414318830180024L;

    private Collection<AppSite> appSites = new HashSet<AppSite>();
```

GroupDAO.java:

```
public class GroupDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Group getGroupById(Long id){
        Group group = getHibernateTemplate().get(Group.class, id);
        return group;
}
```

Here is the jsp that loops these records:

```
<p>Number of items: ${fn:length(groupCommand.group.appSites)}</p>

<ul>
    <c:forEach items="${groupCommand.group.appSites}" var="appSite">
        <li><a href="../appsites/appsite.page?appSiteId=${appSite.appSiteId}">${appSite.nameEng}</a></li>   
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

The problem is that appSite.nameEng isn't sorted properly. How does one do this?

So far, I have this HQL:

`from Group as g inner join g.appSites as s where g.appSiteGroupId=10 order by s.nameEng asc`

In Eclipse/Hibernate HQL Editor, it returns the proper amount of records. However, when I change my DAO method to this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Group getGroupById(Long id){
    //Group group = getHibernateTemplate().get(Group.class, id);
    Group group = (Group) getHibernateTemplate().find("from Group as g inner join g.appSites as s where g.appSiteGroupId=10 order by s.nameEng asc").get(0);
    return group;
}
```

I get this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to org.domain.Group`

**Update #1**

I have this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Group getGroupById(Long id){
    //Group group = getHibernateTemplate().get(Group.class, id);
    List<Group> groupList= getHibernateTemplate().find("from Group as g inner join g.appSites as s where g.appSiteGroupId=10 order by s.nameEng asc");
    return (groupList.size() > 0 ) ? groupList.get(0) : null; //line 17
}
```

The resulting error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to org.domain.Group
    org.dao.GroupDAO.getGroupById(GroupDAO.java:17)
```

**Update #2**

Another try, same problem

Group.java

```
public class Group implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Collection<AppSite> appSites = new ArrayList<AppSite>();
```

AppSiteComparator.java

```
public class AppSiteComparator implements Comparator<AppSite> {

    private String sortBy;

    public AppSiteComparator(String sortBy){
        this.sortBy = sortBy;
    }

    public AppSiteComparator(){
        this.sortBy = "nameEng";
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(AppSite a1, AppSite a2){
        if(this.sortBy.equals("nameEng"))
            return a1.getNameEng().compareTo(a2.getNameEng());
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

GroupDAO.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Group getGroupById(Long id){
    Group group = getHibernateTemplate().get(Group.class, id);
    Collections.sort((List<AppSite>) group.getAppSites(), new AppSiteComparator());
    return group;
}
```

Error

`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at org.dao.GroupDAO.getGroupById(GroupDAO.java:19)`

**Update #3**

Tried using Criteria:

```
Group group = (Group) session.createCriteria(Group.class)                   
    .createAlias("appSites", "a")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("appSiteGroupId",10L))
    .addOrder(Order.asc("a.nameEng")).list().get(0);
```

Still not working... order displayed in console:

```
Site name: test 4
Site name: Test eng
Site name: test 2
Site name: test 3
```

Just noticed... SQL seems to be right:

`Hibernate: select from serverlist.configtool_group this_ inner join serverlist.configtool_app_site a1_ on this_.app_site_group_id=a1_.app_site_group_id where this_.app_site_group_id=? order by a1_.name_eng asc`

I was wrong... the appSites property was set in another SQL, and it doesn't have any sort:

`Hibernate: select ... from serverlist.configtool_app_site appsites0_ where appsites0_.app_site_group_id=?`

Answer (score 0):

*`appSite.nameEng` is not sorted properly*

The type of your `appSite` is `HashSet`. So by nature there is no order in it.

*Cause of the ClassCastException:*

In your query:

```
from Group as g inner join g.appSites as s where g.appSiteGroupId=10 order by s.nameEng asc
```

You are joining (inner) two entities (`Group` and `AppSite`), so the result of the query is certainly not of `Group` entity type. You should use `list()` method of `Query` class, to process this kind of queries.

Comment: Would you know of an alternative to accomplish the sorting? By using Criterias instead? Also, I had done an output of the class name of the result, I got java.lang.Object. That should have indicated my issue.

Comment: Yes, Criterias are good alternative for you and you should use, `List` instead of `Set`.`find` method always returns `Object` and yes it indicated your issue by throwing `Exception`.

Comment: see update #3, I was sure I was going to get what I wanted... alas, didn't work.